# Why all of physical memory must be mapped for initializing the free pages list?

Tags: xv6

The [companion book](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/xv6/book-rev8.pdf) says at page 32 that

> There is a bootstrap problem: all of physical memory must be mapped in
>   order for the allocator to initialize the free list, but creating a
>   page table with those mappings involves allocating page-table pages.

I don't understand why. Why doesn't the kernel just fill all the 4K pages from `[end,PHYSTOP)` with the `struct run` as it does for range `[end,4M)`?

Why all the physical memory must be already mapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are a lot more pages in `[end, PHYSTOP)`, not 4K.

Now for you're question (if I understand it right).

When we boot to xv6 we use `entrypgdir` as our effective page directory, which maps only [0, 4MB). These are the only addresses we can access. Therefore we can map only these pages with `freerange()`.

Right after `kinit1()`, which allocates first 4MB after the end of kernel code, we allocate a new page directory (`kpgdir`). This page directory will allows us to reach further in memory for it is mapping all of our memory (see `setupkvm()`).